# Was my codeigniter Update successful or not?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am using the Active Record in Code Igniter and I have the following code in my controller for my profile:

```
$data = array(
  'first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
  'last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
  'email_address' => $_POST['email_address'],
  'gravatar_email' => $_POST['gravatar_email']
);

$this->db->where('user_id', $session_data['id']);
$this->db->update('user_profiles', $data);

redirect('profile', 'refresh');
```

How do I do the redirect only if the update was successful or not? Also I would like to display a message to my user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be accessing `$_POST` directly, there are helpers for that (`$this->input->post('name')` since they sanitize the data when used properly).

Secondly, you use something like `$this->db->affected_rows();` to determine *how many* rows were changed and then judge what happened.

In your update, you might update *1* element, or *x*, you need to test for that before doing a redirect.

Hope that helps, when all else fails, read the **CI** guide, it is very well written.

**Reference:**
[Query Helpers](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html)
[Input Class / POST / GET etc;](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html)

Comment: but `$this->db->affected_rows();` will return 0 if same value is updated.right?

Comment: if you add a field like current time then the recored will show as updated even if the form values are the same (if thats what you want)